# Office 2013 Style for MFC Ribbon Application

Tags: mfc, styles, ribbon

is there a way to change the Style of a MFC Ribbon Application to the Office 2013 Style/Look?
I´ve searched with Google but didn´t find anything. I´d be happy if someone can help me.

Comment: I´m writing my own MFC-Application and chose "Ribbon" as Menu Type (I did not install any 3rd-Party Packages).

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon Style is available since the VS-2010 Feature Pack.